# Central vertices lie in the diametral path if they ar adjacent in the graph?????

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is it true that central vertices (adjacent central vertices) of a graph always lie in every diametral path? Few graphs satisfy this property. But no idea how to prove it? Can anyone provide some hint/help to prove/disprove it?

Comment: Not every central vertex lie on every diametral path. Consider $C_4$.

Comment: Oh yes.... thank you very much.

Comment: @Smylic edited my question.... can you help now please.

Comment: More strong statement: it is false that every central vertex lie on at least one central path. Consider $G = (\{\,1, 2, 3, 4, 5\,\}, \{\,\{\,1, 2\,\}, \{\,2, 3\,\}, \{\,3, 4\,\}, \{\,2, 5\,\}, \{\,3, 5\,\}\,\})$. Also one pair of adjacent central vertices belongs to the only diametal path, but two other pairs doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The claim "central vertices of a graph always lie in every diametral path" is not entirely clear, but I can't come up with an interpretation that is true.

If you mean

> If $v$ is a central vertex, then every diametral path contains $v$.

then that is certainly **not true** in general. There are plenty of counterexamples where *every* vertex is central but *no* vertex is on every diameter: Cycle graphs, complete graphs, the graph of every regular polyhedron ...

It is not even true that

> Every diametral path contains at least one central vertex.

which has this counterexample:

```
 A---B
 |\ /|
 | C |
 |/ \|
 D---E
```

where C is the only central vertex, but the path A-B-E is a diameter.

Comment: ...Thanks a lot for answer. It is clear to me now.